# Child travel consent for Lima, Peru

Tags: air-travel, children, peru, lima

My wife and son will be traveling to Peru next month and will return in 45 days. They are both Peruvian citizens, my son is a US citizen and wife is a US green card holder. We've read that a single parent traveling with child may need a travel consent from the second parent when flying out of Peru. What we're unsure of is if we need these documents. The Peruvian consulate website in the US says the documents for a dual citizen are only needed if the stay is longer than 90 days. http://www.consuladoperu.com/general/index.php?consulado=DENVER&pagina=AutorizacionViajeMenor.php But when we finally managed to get a hold of someone at the consulate in the US they spoke fairly poor English and not sure if they completely understood my question. 
I was wondering if anyone here had experience with this? I would ask the consulate rep again, but they are extremely hard to get a hold of.

Comment: What did the consular rep actually tell you ?

Answer (score 3):

If your child leaves after 45 days they shouldn't need an authorization, it's on that page you [reference](http://www.consuladoperu.com/general/index.php?consulado=DENVER&pagina=AutorizacionViajeMenor.php).

> **No se requiere una autorización de viaje:**
>
> a) cuando el niño tiene doble nacionalidad (por ejemplo, peruano y
>   estadounidense) y viaja con el pasaporte/documento de viaje otorgado
>   por las autoridades del país de su otra nacionalidad, salvo que su
>   estadía en el Perú sobrepase los noventa (90) días; y
>
> b) cuando el menor sea residente y tenga los documentos que lo
>   comprueben, salvo que su estadía en el Perú sobrepase los noventa (90)
>   días, en cuyo caso requerirá autorización de viaje para salir del Perú
>   (niños peruanos o extranjeros).

***A travel authorization is not required:***

*a) when the child has dual nationality (for example, Peruvian and US) and is traveling with the passport/document granted by the authorities of the country of his other nationality, except if the stay in Peru exceeds 90 days and*

*b) when the minor is a resident and has documents to prove it, except if the stay in Peru exceeds 90 days, in which case he/she will require an authorization to leave Peru.*

The London [consulate](http://www.conperlondres.com/Html_Files/Tramitesconsulares/salvoconducto_ViajeMenores.htm) says the same thing:

> Los menores peruanos y extranjeros que vivan o hubiesen permanecido en
>   el Perú  más de tres (03) meses, deberán contar con la autorización de
>   viaje de ambos padres al momento de salir de nuestro país. Si no vive
>   en el Perú y ha permanecido menos de tres (03) meses en nuestro país
>   NO necesitan contar con la autorización de sus padres para salir.

*Peruvian and foreign minors who live or have stayed more than 3 months in Peru have to have a travel authorization from both parents at the time of leaving the country. If they don't live in Peru or have stayed less than 3 months in the country, they are NOT required to have a parental authorization to leave.*

The [Toronto](http://www.conperutoronto.com/servicio.php?cid=9) consulate seems to suggest it's required in all cases, obviously the best way to be completely safe is to have it anyway. Just be aware it's more involved than simply filling in a form, so do it as soon as possible. They need a valid DNI (national identity document), notarized birth certificates and identity forms, an itinerary and someone needs to go in person to the consulate for this.

Comment: Hopefully someone with better Spanish can correct any inaccuracies in that translation of mine

Comment: It does not hurt to have such a travel consent form, it will not cost the world and will always be good to have. it will allow your wife and son ease of mind not to get in trouble on the way back home.

Comment: @Willeke of course the best way to be completely safe is to have it anyway, but the question was if they needed it.